# Adding user to an account which has multiple subscriptions

Tags: java, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api, google-reseller-api

If Google Apps account has multiple subscriptions and I'm creating a new user for the account, how can I know which subscription is used to create the user?

Answer (score 0):

A customer domain can only have *ONE* Google Apps subscription -- period.  Any 'arbitrary' license (e.g. Drive, Vault) must be provisioned AFTER the user account has been created by using the License Assignment API.

Comment: From Reseller APIs doc (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/concepts): "A customer can have more than one subscription. A subscription is created by the reseller for each product SKU assigned to a customer."

Comment: While a customer domain can have many subscriptions, it is mandatory to have a Google Apps subscription. Once you have assigned a google apps license for the user, the other licenses can be assigned via license manager